# How to get programmatically only enable CMS pages in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cms, backend

I want to get only **enable CMS** pages I merge my custom array and CMS pages as shown below:

```
<?php

namespace Vender\Module\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Cms\Model\Config\Source\Page;

/**
 * Store Options for Cms Pages and Blocks
 */

class Link implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
    public $dataa = array();
    public function __construct(
        Page $page
    )
    {
        $this->_page = $page;
    }
    public function toOptionArray()
        {
            $this->dataa = [['value' => ' ', 'label' => __('Empty')],['value' => 'customer/account/login', 'label' => __('Login')], 
            ['value' => 'customer/account/create', 'label' => __('SignUp')], ['value' => 'contact', 'label' => __('Contact Us')]];
            $marge = array();
            $marge =  array_merge($this->dataa,$this->_page->toOptionArray());
            return $marge;
        }
```

It returns me all the CMS pages and my custom array as well.
Now I want to get only those pages which are enabled from the admin side.

Answer (score 0):

```
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilderFactory;
use Magento\Cms\Api\PageRepositoryInterface;
```

Now

```
/**
 * @var SearchCriteriaBuilderFactory
 */
private $searchCriteriaBuilderFactory;
/**
 * @var PageRepositoryInterface
 */
private $pageRepository;

public function __construct(
    SearchCriteriaBuilderFactory $searchCriteriaBuilderFactory,
    PageRepositoryInterface $pageRepository
) {
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilderFactory = $searchCriteriaBuilderFactory;
    $this->pageRepository = $pageRepository;

}
```

Now use following way:

```
/** @var SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder */
$searchCriteriaBuilder = $this->searchCriteriaBuilderFactory->create();
$searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('is_active', 1, 'eq');
$searchCriteria = $searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
$cmsPages = $this->pageRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
foreach ($cmsPages as $cmsPage) {
    error_log($cmsPage->getId());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your class constructor

```
protected $pageCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Page\CollectionFactory $pageCollectionFactory,
    ...
) {
    ....
    $this->pageCollectionFactory = $pageCollectionFactory;
    ....
}
```

Then you can use this in one of your class methods.

```
$collection = $this->pageCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addFieldToFilter('is_active',array('eq'=>1));
```